# Why does the button click event mess up my code when inside a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to learn a bit of JavaScript. I tried creating a little game of Simon, and I have encountered an issue I can't understand why it is happening. I have implemented a button click code, that when it is outside a function all the code is working as expected, but once I put it inside the next sequence function in order to be able to have the buttons clickable once the game has started everything gets messed up and it is not working (I can't understand what is not working in this place). Here is the correct code:

```
var buttonColours = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];
var gamePattern = [];
var userClickedPattern = [];
var gameStarted = false;
var level = 0;

$(document).on("keydown", function (e){
    if (gameStarted===false) {
        gameStarted = true;
        var level = 0;
        $("#level-title").text("Level " + level);
        nextSequence();
    }
});

$(".btn").on("click", function () {
    var userChosenColour = $(this).attr("id");
    userClickedPattern.push(userChosenColour);
    playSound(userChosenColour);
    animatePress(userChosenColour);
    checkAnswer(userClickedPattern.length - 1);
});

function nextSequence() {
    userClickedPattern = [];
    level++;
    $("#level-title").text("Level " + level);
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    var randomChosenColour = buttonColours[randomNumber];
    gamePattern.push(randomChosenColour);
    $("#" + randomChosenColour).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
    playSound(randomChosenColour);  
}

function playSound(name) {
    var playAudio = new Audio("./sounds/"+name+".mp3");
    playAudio.play(); 
}

function animatePress(currentColour) {
    $("#" + currentColour).addClass("pressed");
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#" + currentColour).removeClass("pressed")}, 100);
}

function checkAnswer(currentLevel) {
    if(gamePattern[currentLevel] === userClickedPattern[currentLevel]) {
        if (currentLevel === level - 1) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                nextSequence();}, 600);
        }
    } else {
        $("body").addClass("game-over")
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("body").removeClass("game-over");
        }, 200);
        var wrongAudio = new Audio("./sounds/wrong.mp3");
        wrongAudio.play();
        $("#level-title").text("Game Over, Press Any Key to Restart");
        level = 0;
        gamePattern = [];
        gameStarted = false;
    }
}
```

and here is the code with the buttons inside the function:

```
var buttonColours = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];
var gamePattern = [];
var userClickedPattern = [];
var gameStarted = false;
var level = 0;

$(document).on("keydown", function (e){
    if (gameStarted===false) {
        gameStarted = true;
        var level = 0;
        $("#level-title").text("Level " + level);
        nextSequence();
    }
});



function nextSequence() {
    userClickedPattern = [];
    level++;
    $("#level-title").text("Level " + level);
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    var randomChosenColour = buttonColours[randomNumber];
    gamePattern.push(randomChosenColour);
    $("#" + randomChosenColour).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
    playSound(randomChosenColour);  
    $(".btn").on("click", function () {
        var userChosenColour = $(this).attr("id");
        userClickedPattern.push(userChosenColour);
        playSound(userChosenColour);
        animatePress(userChosenColour);
        checkAnswer(userClickedPattern.length - 1);
    });
}

function playSound(name) {
    var playAudio = new Audio("./sounds/"+name+".mp3");
    playAudio.play(); 
}

function animatePress(currentColour) {
    $("#" + currentColour).addClass("pressed");
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#" + currentColour).removeClass("pressed")}, 100);
}

function checkAnswer(currentLevel) {
    if(gamePattern[currentLevel] === userClickedPattern[currentLevel]) {
        if (currentLevel === level - 1) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                nextSequence();}, 600);
        }
    } else {
        $("body").addClass("game-over")
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("body").removeClass("game-over");
        }, 200);
        var wrongAudio = new Audio("./sounds/wrong.mp3");
        wrongAudio.play();
        $("#level-title").text("Game Over, Press Any Key to Restart");
        level = 0;
        gamePattern = [];
        gameStarted = false;
    }
}
```

With the code that it is not working I expected to have the same results as with the working code, with the difference that the buttons would be clickable only once the game started.

Comment: `$(".btn").on("click", function () {` attaches the `function` to the `"click"` event. Thus, that doesn't happen until `nextSequence` is called.

Comment: But it _would_ add a new, _additional_ click handler, every time `nextSequence` is called - which is probably not what you'd want to begin with.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise your title to actually _ask_ the question and not just state that you have one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first example you attach button click event listener only once.

In second you attach it every time `nextSequence` function is called. This means that that code will be executed multiple times on click.

To make second example work you need to remove previous click event listener before assigning a new one. To remove event listener with JQuery you can use off function: https://api.jquery.com/off. Just put that function into a separate line and name it (like you did with `nextSequence` function) so event listener has the reference to it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am still trying to wrap my head around how this is functioning (sorry really new with javascript). Why is it executed multiple times on click. I call the nextsequence function, i click something and the handler runs for the click, then at some point in the future i call again the function and press another button, why more handlers are happening?

Comment: When your are assigning an event handler using `$.on`, you're actually **adding** that function to any pre-existing handlers, which will, whenever the event occurs, be run sequentially in the order they have been attached to that event. The native DOM API makes this clearer, where it's not called `on()` but rather `addEventListener()`.

Comment: *every* time you call `nextSequence()` you *add* another click handler.  You call `nextSequence` every time you start a new game and every time you check the current level.    Move `$(".btn").on("click", function () {` so that it is outside of `nextSequence`